# How to access controls inside DataRepeater?

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

I'm trying to get a value from a DataRepeater Control in C#
The old program (written in VB) did this with this instruction:

```
If CBool(e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(Temp_S.Name).Text) = True Then
  e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(T_S.Name).Text = "S"
  e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(T_S.Name).BackColor = Color.Yellow
  e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(T_S.Name).ForeColor = Color.Black
Else
  e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(T_S.Name).BackColor = Color.White
  e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls(T_S.Name).ForeColor = Color.White
End If
```

I try with the same instruction in C# but without result.
The error that appear is:

> "Non-invocable member 'Control.controls' cannot be used like a method."

Edit:
I found a solution but it still doesn't work even if it doesn't produce errors and, very strange, if I put a stop point inside the sub for inspect it the point is never reached! It appears like this sub is never reached!

```
private void DataRepeater_Buoni_DrawItem(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Accende S
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["t_Buono.Name"].Text = "10268"))
  {
    e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["t_S.Name"].Text = "S";
    e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["t_S.Name"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["t_S.Name"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }
  else
  {
    e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls[t_S.Name].BackColor = Color.White;
    e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls[t_S.Name].ForeColor = Color.White;
  }
}
```

Comment: `It appears like this sub is never reached`  That would be a different problem.

Comment: @LarsTech, i insert the complete code....how is possible this??

Comment: Did you subscribe to the `DrawItem` event?

Comment: @LarsTech, what do you mean with "subscribe"?

Comment: `Sub DataRepeater1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DataRepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles DataRepeater1.DrawItem`

Comment: Ok, i was able to make the sub working!!Alleluja. But when i try to check if the field specified at the beginning of this threat contains "true" or "false"the sub still doesn't work with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls[Temp_S.Name] as Control).Text`

Modified Code:

```
// Change TextBox to the actual type of your control
var control = e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls[Temp_S.Name] as TextBox; 
if (control != null)
{
    string textValue = control.Text;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly doesn't work!

Comment: Try the modified one.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY IT WORKS!!!!!

```
if (e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["temp_S"].Text == "True")
```

The problem was the .Name joined with the textbox name.
Thanks to everybody for the support!